# json_decode returning NULL with valid json

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, json

so...here's the issue:

I got this on my javascript file:

```
this.fields = {
  'zone': ['DouroMinho','TrasosMontes', 'BeiraLitoral', 'BeiraInterior'],
  'flower': ['Milho Grao', 'Milho', 'Prado', 'Batata', 'Couve', 'Tomateiro', 'Pessegueiro', 'Pomoideas', 'Vinha'],
  'Months': ['Janeiro', 'Fevereiro', 'Março', 'Abril', 'Maio', 'Junho', 'Julho', 'Agosto', 'Setembro', 'Outubro', 'Novembro', 'Dezembro']
}

var sendDataToText = $.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost:4000/process-data.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: { 'input-data': JSON.stringify(this.fields) },
    cache: false,
    dataType: json,
    success: function(data){
      console.log('call to process-data successful');
      return;
    },
    error: function() { console.log("process-data falhou"); return; }
  });
```

and on my php i got this:

```
if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()){
$d = stripslashes($_POST['input-data']);
}else{
$d = $_POST['input-data'];
}
$d = json_decode($d,true);

echo var_dump($d);
```

I have MAMP running my server and gulp running the wep app on port 3000.
When i go to localhost:4000 to test my process-data.php it only shows NULL.

What's wrong? the json_decode error returns 0, which means the json_decode is not the problem. The json is also valid and turned into string before the ajax call. Help please, lol. Thank you

Comment: Are you sure you are sending data to the server? Try debugging both your JavaScript and your PHP to see where it fails. Looking at your code I think you may be sending empty data on the ajax call since you're using `this.fields` and `this` may be getting lost in scope.

Comment: For an example of `this` and scope issues, see: http://javascriptplayground.com/blog/2012/04/javascript-variable-scope-this/

Comment: im using riotjs, and the javascript i talked about is a 'tag', which is compiled into javascript, i debugged on the server (por 3000) and this.fields is the variable field refering to 'this' tag, and it shows on the console, the json. I also tried passing to the php function which writes to file raw data like "stuff", and it writes to file. I'm really confused :|

Comment: I don't know about riotjs, but I tried using your code (substituting the serverside call for my own test script) and the javascript json encoded string is `undefined`. If I change `this.fields` to just `fields` i get an actual json string. Also, you need quotes around the dataType parameter in your ajax request: `dataType: 'json',`

Comment: thanks for the effort mason :) , i fixed the 'json' part but still nothing changed. About the undefined..i got that fixed for me because im using the library i told you, Riot Js, so it works on my side, the whole object is printed on chrome dev tool's console :). I guess ill keep trying more stuff...thanks a lot anyway man!

Comment: You're welcome. I'm sorry I couldn't help more. I am curious though, where were you outputing the json in the console. I added `console.log(JSON.stringify(this.fields));` inside both the success and error callback functions of the ajax call.

Comment: I don't know much about riot js (looking at it now), but I do know that scope is a pesky thing. When you define `this.fields` the scope of `this` is probably the `window` object. When your reference `this` from inside the ajax code, you are referencing the jquery ajax request object instance you are defining. Try adding `console.log(this);` right after you define `this.fields` and then again inside your success and error callbacks.

Comment: i tried this:

    $violinos = "{
      'zone': ['DouroMinho','TrasosMontes', 'BeiraLitoral', 'BeiraInterior'],
      'flower': ['Milho Grao', 'Milho', 'Prado', 'Batata', 'Couve', 'Tomateiro', 'Pessegueiro', 'Pomoideas', 'Vinha'],
      'Months': ['Janeiro', 'Fevereiro', 'Março', 'Abril', 'Maio', 'Junho', 'Julho', 'Agosto', 'Setembro', 'Outubro', 'Novembro', 'Dezembro']
    }";

$violinos = json_decode($violinos);

print_r($violinos);

die();

And on the localhost:4000 (to test the php) it's blank...

Comment: But in the previous code, if i remove the json_decode, it returns the json correctly so the problem isn't the scope. The problem is the json_decode function somehow...

Comment: OK the PHP code you provided in your comment shows part of the problem, it is invalid JSON (at least in terms of how json_decode works). Here is a test you can compare with: http://ideone.com/v4fHcx

Comment: so the problem is the "" , it should be ' '  ?? but i'm using JSON.stringify(this.fields) on the ajax call, this takes the js object and puts two ' ' turning it to a string... :o

Comment: See also: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php `Example #3 common mistakes using json_decode()`

Comment: That's the point I'm trying to make, are you absolutely certain that you have the right scope for your javascript? Did you actually put the console logs in the success and error callbacks like I suggested? What did you get in the console output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that you are losing the fields json to improper usage of scope.

In the OP code you are assigning fields to `this` which is most likely the `window` object. When you are accessing it in the `$.ajax` object you are still using `this` which no longer has `window` scope, but rather the scope of the ajax object.

Try this:

```
window.fields = {
  'zone': ['DouroMinho','TrasosMontes', 'BeiraLitoral', 'BeiraInterior'],
  'flower': ['Milho Grao', 'Milho', 'Prado', 'Batata', 'Couve', 'Tomateiro', 'Pessegueiro', 'Pomoideas', 'Vinha'],
  'Months': ['Janeiro', 'Fevereiro', 'Março', 'Abril', 'Maio', 'Junho', 'Julho', 'Agosto', 'Setembro', 'Outubro', 'Novembro', 'Dezembro']
}

var sendDataToText = $.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost:4000/process-data.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: { 'input-data': JSON.stringify(window.fields) },
    cache: false,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data){
      console.log('call to process-data successful');
      return;
    },
    error: function() { 
      console.log("process-data falhou"); 
      return; 
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 3):

use a variable to save the context (scope) when the data from the success comes in:

```
var something;

$.ajax({
    ...,
    success: function(data){
        console.log('call to process-data successful');
        something = data;
    },
...
console.log(something);
```

Comment: That was also a issue! But you fixed that, thanks a lot!